# set list view adapter in a fragment in android

Tags: android, listview, adapter, fragment

I want a custom row, so I am using a List View in an xml and inflating into a fragment. I am very confused of how to set the adapter for the list View. 
I created a new adapter which extends Base Adapter. In the getView method, I really don't know what context to pass while inflating the row.xml layout. 
How do I set the adapter for the list view and where?

```
public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment{


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.results_layout, container, false);
        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.results);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        loadPage(dataBean.getWhat(), dataBean.getWhere(), dataBean.getPageStart());

        //resultsAdapter.setRssData(rssData);
        //setListAdapter(resultsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        resultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(context);
    }





    /**
     * Set List Adapter
     */
    private void setAdapter(){
        if(listView.getAdapter() == null){
            listView.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);
        }
        else{
            resultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: ResultsAdapter(getActivity()); this should work i think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must extend `Listfragment` (instead of `Fragment`), and using its `ListFragment.setListAdapter` to set your adapter. In the adapter `getView()` inflate your row.. that s all

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) from the type ListFragment

Comment: @SureshParmar, it is not a static method. If you are extending `ListFragment`, the method is on `this`

Answer (score 10):

If you do not want to change your extended class, you should use `listview.setAdapter(...)` method. As you see in my example :

```
ListView productList= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.product_list);


    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());


    adapter.add(new SampleItem(
            "Sunny LCD TV 2\"  SN022L66-T1 Full HD",
            R.drawable.product_sample_pic);


    productList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @Johnson Page Not Found :(

Comment: it solved but help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446088/how-to-get-alert-dialog-spinner-values-in-textview