# Set parent's activity list from a child fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which works as a pager. In this activty there are some fragments, and a ListView. Is it possible that I set the list adapter on my activity from one of my fragments?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!how can it be done?is it something like getActivity().setListAdapter?

Comment: possibly duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618409/set-list-view-adapter-in-a-fragment-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618409/set-list-view-adapter-in-a-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `Activity` that holds the `Fragment` by calling `getActivity()` after `onActivityCreated()` in the `Fragment`s lifecycle.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);
  lv.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [**ViewPager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead of inveting all by yourself. Follow the link and you will find example on using this android feature. Also, it's backward-compatible using the support library.

If it helps you what to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ListAdapter` for that.
Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)